# Address book with AJAX/PHP/MySQL - full project in 1 file:)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, ajax

As a ambitious dream:S I would like to learn AJAX through a little address book project. My idea was to have something in IPAD style as on the left hand side would be a contact list and as you select one the other part of the screen would fill the contact form in to be able to alter or just display it.

My SQL structure is:

```
Contact         |  Address  |  Email

id                 id          id
contact_first      address1    email
contact_sur        address2
contac_mobil       town
email_id           postcode
address_id         country
```

I am not asking from someone write it for me - that would be silly:) but I am asking the community to give me bits so I can understand and put together - more importantly I can alter or even expand later - something that I would test as a homework. I would like to build up the 'best practice' solution, if possible.

Hope this silly game can be accommodated here.

Any idea would be really appreciated.

addressbook.php - my initial though

```
<?php 
include("db_con1.php"); 

// left side people list
$peoplelist='SELECT contact_first, contact_sur, contact_mobil FROM contactmain WHERE status=1';
$queryl = $pdo->prepare($peoplelist);
$queryl->execute();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">

<html>
<head>
<title>Email sending program</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/adminolok.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">
</head>

<body>
<?php include("menu.php"); ?>


<div id="leftnavigation">
<ul>
<?php foreach ($queryl as $i => $rowl) { ?>
 <li >
  <label for="contact_<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <span class="name">
     <?php echo $rowl['contact_first'].' <strong>'.$rowl['contact_sur'].'</strong>'; ?>
    </span>
    <br />
    <span class="mobil"><?php echo $rowl['contact_mobil'];?></span>
  </label>
 <?php  }?>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="midtop">

<form method="post" action="test.php">
<ul>
  <li><label class="description">Name</label>
   <div>
    <input type="text" name="first" /><label class="fieldname">First</label>
    <input type="text" name="first" /><label class="fieldname">Surname</label>
   </div>
  </li>
  <li><label class="description">Mobil</label>
   <div>
    <input type="text" name="mobil" /><label class="fieldname">mobil num</label>
  </div>
  </li>
  <li><label class="description">Email</label>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="email" /><label class="fieldname">email</label>
  </div>
  </li>
<input type="submit" name="save">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Update log:)

- I had an answer on the Jquery() refresh - thanks for that
- Left hand side questions:

1, if you have a limited screen (IPAD) and you've got 3000 contact names what is the best to show them in a list?

2, if you need to scroll, how would you do to make sure it will work on iOS/Android as well?

- test 1 went well so I am fixing all the typo errors - works so far
- next question: how to pass the record to the right hand side panel - in the form?

any answer would be appreciated

Comment: thanks I got some previous lessons on Stackoverflow:)

Comment: I don't think this really fits in SO. That being said... what about separating your PHP logic from the HTML code? Also, for your AJAX requests, consider using jQuery

Comment: thanks for the comment! I do appreciate why you're saying this however I have had a couple of project supported by SO and there is always a bit which is missing. I though if people can see the whole in one they might use different suggestion. MORE IMPORTANTLY I would like to see the comments as a learning curve, if possible.

Comment: @shesek do you mean different files or just the codes in the file?

Comment: Use DIV's instead of SPAN's when you want to breakline, instead of using BR's!

Answer (score 1):

*I assume that you want no refresh on your page (only ajax requests)*

*I suggest that you use jQuery so ajax resquests are a lot easier to do, and i will use jQuery in my examples*

Here's how i would make it:

When you click on a contact, get this contact details by ajax (address, town, etc) and display it in form on the right side:

```
$("#leftside label").click(function() {
  $.get('getContactInfo.php?contact=' + $(this).attr('for'), function(data) {
    $('#rightside').html(data);
  });
});
```

When you submit the form on the right side, send an ajax request to modify the contact/address/email edited. Don't forget to update the left side info.

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "editContactInfo.php",
    data: $("#myform").serialize()
    success: function(msg) {
      // here you have to update the submited info in the left side
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks very much your help. I am looking forward to build the whole project with the community:) thanks again

Comment: Can we have other people opinions as well - let's do a brainstorm session, shall we?

Comment: In the head of the document or footer, inside script tags :D